Error "Authenticated IAM principal does not seeem authorized to make API request" connecting to CloudSQL from GKE FastAPI application
Question
Unable to connect due to error -
Cluster info -
Name - second-cluster
IP Type - public
Service account - testserviceaccount
Service account has the following enabled - 
Artifact Registry Service Agent
Cloud SQL Admin
Cloud SQL Client
Compute Engine Service Agent
Editor
Kubernetes Engine Service Agent

CloudSQL -
Public IP - enabled
I have set the DB_IAM_USER to be testserviceaccount.
Error -
    resp = await self._client.get(url, headers=headers, raise_for_status=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 696, in _request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 1070, in raise_for_status
    raise ClientResponseError(
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message="Forbidden: Authenticated IAM principal does not seeem authorized to make API request. Verify 'Cloud SQL Admin API' is enabled within your GCP project and 'Cloud SQL Client' role has been granted to IAM principal.", url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/testingdev-420720/instances/modam/connectSettings')
ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 732, in lifespan
    async with self.lifespan_context(app) as maybe_state:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 210, in __aenter__
    return await anext(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/assistantservice/main.py", line 12, in lifespan
    init_db()
  File "/app/assistantservice/config/databaseconfig.py", line 70, in init_db
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 5825, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3254, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3244, in begin
    with self.connect() as conn:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3280, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 146, in __init__
    self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3304, in raw_connection
    return self.pool.connect()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 449, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1263, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 712, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 179, in _do_get
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 177, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 390, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 674, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 900, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 146, in __exit__
    raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 896, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in <lambda>
    return lambda rec: creator_fn()
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/app/assistantservice/config/databaseconfig.py", line 45, in getconn
    conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/connector.py", line 212, in connect
    return connect_task.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 456, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/google/cloud/sql/connector/refresh_utils.py", line 66, in _is_valid
    metadata = await task
               ^^^^^^^^^^
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientResponseError: 403, message="Forbidden: Authenticated IAM principal does not seeem authorized to make API request. Verify 'Cloud SQL Admin API' is enabled within your GCP project and 'Cloud SQL Client' role has been granted to IAM principal.", url=URL('https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/testingdev-420720/instances/modam/connectSettings')

Code
import pg8000
from os import getenv, environ
from sqlmodel import SQLModel, create_engine, Session
from google.cloud.sql.connector import IPTypes, Connector



DATABASE_URL = None
engine = None

instance_connection_name = environ[
        "INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME"
    ]
    
    db_name = environ["DB_NAME"]  # e.g. 'my-database'

    print("instance connection name: ",instance_connection_name)

    ip_type = IPTypes.PRIVATE if environ.get("PRIVATE_IP") else IPTypes.PUBLIC
    print("IP Type: ", ip_type)

    db_user, db_pass, enable_iam_auth = (
        (getenv("DB_IAM_USER"), "", True)
        if getenv("DB_IAM_USER")
        else (getenv("DB_USER"),getenv("DB_PASS"), False)
    )

    # initialize Cloud SQL Python Connector object
    connector = Connector(enable_iam_auth=enable_iam_auth)

    def getconn() -> pg8000.dbapi.Connection:
        conn: pg8000.dbapi.Connection = connector.connect(
            instance_connection_name,
            "pg8000",
            user=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            db=db_name,
            ip_type=ip_type,
        )
        return conn


What I have tried with the same result -

Deleting the deployment and setting environment variable to the email address of the principal
Using user, pass, dn_name instead of iam.

When I Try to launch the app from local it doesn't throw an error with db_user, pass and name.
